# iPhone: How do I get the title of a PDF document from within the document?

Tags: iphone, pdf, cgpdfdictionaryref

Assuming I have extracted the CGPDFDictionaryRef from a PDF document using the iPhone SDK, how do I get the document's title from the dictionary?  More generally, how can I get a list of the keywords for that dictionary?  In theory I could ask the customer, but surely there must be some canonical keywords?  Is there a list somewhere?

Update: I found this [link](http://pdf.editme.com/pdfua-docinfodictionary) which gives the common keys.  To answer my own question, you can look these up directly in the dictionary returned by CGPDFDocumentGetInfo(pdfDocumentRef).

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary key you're looking for is `kCGPDFContextTitle`.

Here's your [list of keys](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Auxiliary_Dictionary_Keys).

Edit: I'm not sure. I haven't actually used CGPDF -- was just giving an educated guess based on how other Apple frameworks work.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll accept the answer if you can help me with the follow-up question too.  (See above.)